# React Native - Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

In my app, the login function sends the phone number inserted by the user, and if the server returns "success" it is supposed to navigate to another screen. Unfortunately the app returns "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')".

The code is the following:

```
const login = (mobileNumber, navigation) => {
Object.keys(mobileNumber).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(mobileNumber[key]);
});

if (mobileNumber.mobileNumber == null) {
  alert('Please fill Mobile number');
  return;
}

let dataToSend = {mobileNumber: mobileNumber.mobileNumber};
let formBody = [];
for (let key in dataToSend) {
  let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
  let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[key]);
  formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
}
formBody = formBody.join('&');

fetch('https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formBody,
  headers: {
    //Header Defination
    'Content-Type':
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
    // If server response message same as Data Matched
    if (responseJson.status === 'success') {
      alert("Login OK!");
      navigation.navigate('FeedScreen');
    } else {
      console.log('Please check mobile number');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    //Hide Loader
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share console.log of navigation ?

Comment: Sure, here you go: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
at App.js:356:18 in fetch.then.then$argument_0". Is this what you meant? Now I do have "console.log(navigation)" between "alert("Login OK!")" and navigation.navigate('FeedScreen');

Comment: No I asked you to do console.log(navigation) in first lines of the function not inside the api call and it looks like you did console.log of navigation.navigate

Comment: Oh sure, I've added console.log("Navigation is: "+navigation); and the console logs "Navigation is: undefined"

Comment: That's the reason also rest of your code shows undefined. You should be sure that you get some defined object as navigation in your function

Comment: Had a similar issue on header navigation solved in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018455/react-native-navigation-on-top-right-header-button/72018615#72018615 but can't figure out how to apply the same method to this case here.

Comment: This’s probably because you using navigation outside navigation context use this guide instead of passing navigation as an argument https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop